# How to match pairs of characters using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a variable containing a string. This string contains only alphabetic and numeric characters. This string also have a fixed length by *32* characters in length. How I can match using regular expressions if this string have only paired characters by length of *2*, *4*, *8*, *16*?

For example, for similar to this strings:

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345

`Regex.IsMatch` must return `false`.

But for strings similar to this:

> **aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa**5555555555555555

this is a *16*-characters pairs;

> **aaaaaaaa**55555555aaaaaaaa55555555

this is a *8*-characters pairs;

> **aaaa**5555aaaa5555aaaa5555aaaa5555

this is a *4*-characters pairs;

> **aa**55aa55aa55aa55aa55aa55aa55aa55

this is a *2*-characters pairs -

`Regex.IsMatch` must return `true`.

Comment: You can't use `IsMatch` here. Find all matches and make sure their size is 2,4,8 or 16.

Comment: @MariusBancila, Thank you. I just realized that I can split text by chunks and check if there is any matches present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Apparently, the requirement is simply to match eg `aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnoopp`, ie the first two characters must be the same, then the next two etc for exactly 32 characters. That can be easily tested for with:

```
((\w)\2(\w)\3){8}
```

Comment: Great! Will check this now. Thank you!

Comment: Tried this one. Nice to see it works! But... this can match `aa55aa55aa55aa55aa55aa55aa55aa55` but not `aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnoopp`. Probably my bad when asks a question... Thank you!

Comment: @hearound, if that is the case, then a single regex should cover every case for you: `((\w)\2{1}(\w)\3{1}){8}`. It simply works on the idea that the first two characters must be the same, then the next two etc for exactly 32 characters.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Now question seems solved. :-)

Comment: Basically the same as `(?:(\w)\1){16}`

Answer (score 0):

This should work (without needing to come up with individual regexes for each possible combination).

```
public bool isRelevantMatch(string inputString)
{
    int matchCount = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"([a-zA-Z])\1{1}").Count;
    return matchCount == 1 || 
           matchCount == 2 || 
           matchCount == 4 || 
           matchCount == 8 ||
           matchCount == 16;
}
```

Explanation: get the count of matches of repeated characters (using a backreference regex to match any instance of aa, AA, bb, BB, etc.).  If that count is 1, 2, 4, **or** 8, return true (there are 2, 4, 8, or 16 paired characters in the string).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm tried this function. This successfully matched pairs but I want to check if string contains only pairs, with fixed length. For example, this one `aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnoopp` is good match, but this one `aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooxz` is bad, because two last characters is not similar. Think that is my bad when question ask. Thank you!

Comment: If you add `|| matchCount == 16`, your first case passes (there's 16 pairs).  Your second case fails either way (there's 15 pairs).

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Now question seems solved. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Late to this but will throw out this.

If you want to do repeating '*unique pairs*' this works in Perl.
I tried to make this smaller but couldn't figure out how.

The syntax for Dot-Net is probably the same. However, I've reused the
capture group names, which works in Perl, but not sure about Dot-Net
(should be ok, if not change to unique names).

Also, in Perl, could have used a branch reset to overlay capture groups,
then test a single group length to get the repeat order, but this is not available in Dot-Net.
So, just have to test 4 groups for a match (or length) to get the order.

```
 # (?<A>(?<b>\w)\k<b>(?!\k<b>)(?<c>\w)\k<c>)\k<A>{7}|(?<A>(?<b>\w)\k<b>{3}(?!\k<b>)(?<c>\w)\k<c>{3})\k<A>{3}|(?<A>(?<b>\w)\k<b>{7}(?!\k<b>)(?<c>\w)\k<c>{7})\k<A>{1}|(?<A>(?<b>\w)\k<b>{15}(?!\k<b>)(?<c>\w)\k<c>{15}) 


   (?<A>                         # (1 start), 2 char pairs, repeating x 8
        (?<b> \w )                    # (2)
        \k<b> 

        (?! \k<b> )
        (?<c> \w )                    # (3)
        \k<c> 
   )                             # (1 end)
   \k<A>{7} 
|  
   (?<A>                         # (4 start), 4 char pairs, repeating x 4
        (?<b> \w )                    # (5)
        \k<b>{3} 

        (?! \k<b> )
        (?<c> \w )                    # (6)
        \k<c>{3} 
   )                             # (4 end)
   \k<A>{3} 

|  
   (?<A>                         # (7 start), 8 char pairs, repeating x 2
        (?<b> \w )                    # (8)
        \k<b>{7} 

        (?! \k<b> )
        (?<c> \w )                    # (9)
        \k<c>{7} 
   )                             # (7 end)
   \k<A>{1} 
|  
   (?<A>                         # (10 start), 16 char pairs
        (?<b> \w )                    # (11)
        \k<b>{15} 

        (?! \k<b> )
        (?<c> \w )                    # (12)
        \k<c>{15} 
   )                             # (10 end)
```